# cannot access to Json with restler library

Tags: php, restler

I create an rest api with php usring restler libary, its work well in my PC but when I uploaded the api to server, problems begin..
this function in my api

```
<?php
class user {
/**
        @url GET /
*/
    public function getAllInfo(){
        $link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=---;charset=utf8','---','-----');
        $handle = $link->prepare('select * from user');
        $handle->execute();
        $result = $handle->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if(empty($result)){
            $err = new stdClass();
            $err->error = "No user found";
            return $err;
        }
        else{
            return $result;
        }
}

require_once 'restler.php';

$r = new Restler(); 
$r->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat'); 
$r->addAPIClass('user'); 
$r->handle();
?>
```

when I access to this page nothing appear in browser
I thought the problem is this page can't access to `require_once 'restler.php';`
but I was wrong, because whan I print `$r->handle();` like this `print_r($r->handle());`
this is what I see in browser

```
Luracast\Restler\EventDispatcher Object ( [listeners:Luracast\Restler\EventDispatcher:private] => Array ( ) [events:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

I don't know what is that or what I should do to print my json,
my database is full of data, its return json if my query doesn't have restler, but I need use restler with my code